# How to lock the orientation of WPF application

Tags: wpf

Is there an API  to lock the orientation of my WPF  application to run only in the landscape mode.

i could find  event that could fire on orientation change, but is there a way to lock it

Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a way in WPF to lock it, you could provide a rotation layout transformation to the root container. It is not actually locking the orientation but rotating your application. Something like this,

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

Read here,

[Layout Transformation](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/19/layouttransform-vs-rendertransform-whats-the-difference.html)

Comment: can you please elaborate it a bit more

Comment: what do you want to know more?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who arrives at this question and is left needing more detail, here is a fully detailed answer...

It appears that as tablet rotation support was done at the individual vendor level, there isn’t much support for it in Windows 7 / 8 other than detecting that there was a change in rotation. The screen can still be pseudo-locked into a landscape format with a bit of XAML sleight of hand. Here’s some sample code that I knocked up last night and tested on my tablet PC…

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="LockRotationWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LockRotationWpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
        <Grid.RenderTransform >
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle}" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="100" Text="Landscape"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Angle}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using LockRotationWpf.ViewModels;

namespace LockRotationWpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var vm = new MainWindowViewModel();
            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModels\MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using LockRotationWpf.Annotations;

namespace LockRotationWpf.ViewModels
{
    // Omit the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation if already implemented on a base ViewModel class.
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public double _angle;

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += DisplaySettingsChanged;
        }

        private void DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Angle = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight > System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth ? -90 : 0;
        }

        public double Angle
        {
            get { return _angle; }
            set
            {
                _angle = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Here are a couple of screen-shots that show the change in orientation. If you’re running an App full screen you won’t get the window chrome and you’d be unaware that the screen had actually rotated. Any on-screen keyboard which opens in response to a text input will of course still pop-up in the portrait position, but the fact that the content is always landscape should give the operator enough of a hint to turn the tablet around for input.

> [image: Holding the tablet in Landscape orientation]
>
> [image: Holding the tablet in Portrait orientation]

I hope that helps anyone who lands here.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences")]
    private static extern UInt32 SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences8(UInt32 orientation);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel", EntryPoint = "SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences")]
    private static extern UInt32 SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences7(UInt32 orientation);

    public MyWindow() 
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And on load of my main window :

```
  SetDisplayAutoRotationPreferences8(2);//Lanscape
```

Comment: where did you put the 1st snippet?

Comment: Just before the constructor.